# How do I invoke a text editor from the terminal?

Tags: macos, compilation, terminal

In the Windows command prompt, I can type `notepad helloworld.cpp` which will then create a *.cpp* file with the name *helloworld* and open up Notepad for me.

Is there a similar function for Mac Terminal, preferably with Textmate or Textedit?

I'm running Mac OS X Lion 10.7, with Xcode developers tool.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There are plenty of ways. Try:

1. `vi <filename you want to save or open.cpp>`,
2. `pico`,
3. `Open /Applications/TextEdit.app <filename>`.

Comment: @Ceetang: at the shell prompt, type "man 1 open" to read the details of how point three on this list works.

Comment: how would i be able to compile the app for windows (.exe extension)?

Comment: pico is nice!! +1

Comment: as known as `nano`

Answer (score 124):

```
open -e <filename>
```

The option `-e` is used to open the file `<filename>` with TextEdit.

Comment: You can first call `touch <filename>` before `open` if the file doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 16):

Simply use `open <filename>` command as described in this [article](http://osxdaily.com/2007/02/01/how-to-launch-gui-applications-from-the-terminal/). It will open an app associated with the file type.

Use `open -e` to open /Applications/TextEdit

Answer (score 10):

About some of the previous suggestions here - you can use `open` command combined with `a` flag to open a file with specific application:

`open -a [appname] [filename]`

but if `[filename]` doesn't exist it displays an error `the file doesn't exists` or something like that, and doesn't create the required file, as you have requested.

Write the following to your `~/.bashrc` file (if that file doesn't exists, you can create it by writing `touch ~/.bashrc` inside the terminal):

```
open2()
{
  touch $2
  open -a $1 $2
}
```

And use it like this:

`open2 [appname] [filename]`

Note that `appname` is an application in your installed application folder (`/Applications`).

The command `touch` creates you the required file (don't worry, if the file exists it won't remove / reset the current file, only redefine the modification time to the current time).

Answer (score 7):

The problem with:

```
open -e
```

or

```
open -a TextEdit
```

is that you have no control on the TextEdit.app modes: Plain Text or RichText.

E.g. if you try to open an HTML file, TextEdit will open it in the Rich Text mode, not in the Plain Text mode, as expected. Then switching to the Plain Text mode will not show the HTML tags.
I could not find a Terminal command to activate the Open option:

```
Ignore rich text commands
```

or the Preference setting:

```
Display HTML files as HTML code instead of formatted text
```

As far as I can see, even an osascript won't solve the case.

This is unfortunate since TextEdit.app is the only text editor that is present for sure. Not all Mac users have installed BBedit, TextMate, or any other third party editor and even less users have defined a "default editor".

Answer (score 5):

If your using text mate you can set it up to work with terminal

```
ln -s /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/mate ~/bin/mate
```

Taken from

http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html

Once you've got mate into your path you can type the following into the terminal

```
mate helloworld.cpp
```

if you want text mate to display all files in a folder as a project drawer

```
mate .
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

`nano <filename you want to open>`

Comment: I like this eloquent answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Preferences (⌘+,) & install shell support.
[image: Like here]

Then you could open any files from terminal with:

```
open file.txt
```

or

```
mate file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question, for me, was:

`leafpad`

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, you can just run `open <file-name>` on the terminal to open the relevant file.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Monterey version 12.4 command `open` would help you. After this command you should put a space and then type the file path using `/` for example:
`open /Users/your_username/desktop/filename.txt`